# Triple 2 x 8 fir beam with span of 12 feet. Will beam support hoist load of 1250 lbs

Tags: beam, load

Triple 2 x 8 fir beam with span of 12 feet.  Will beam support hoist load of 1250 lbs

Comment: There is nothing above the beam?  Is the load in the center of the beam?

Comment: Nothing above the beam. The load is in the center of the span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-header-weight-supported-d_1898.html

Extrapolated for (3)2x8 at 12' span, looks like it should be good.  You might end up with more deflection (bending of the beam) than would be ideal for a door header where the deflection would interfere with door swing.  Not sure why they'd not list the value for 12' span for (3) 2x8 in chart.

These values have safety factors included and wood is designed for rigidity not for values where if you exceed it will fail, if you used under the typical design you end up with more deflection or less rigidity.

Comment: 2x8 at 12 ft span is kind of pushing it for load bearing use, for human safety.  Agree it should work, at least till you place a 100,000 dollar ming vase under the load hoisted.

Comment: I made a load bearing window header out of 2x4s, approved by my engineer for a window in a basement where I wanted the header to be as height small as possible.  It was spanning 4' and had 2x10s above it.  I had > 8" of width available for the member since it was bearing onto an 8' concrete wall so just built it up - maybe 4 of them.

Comment: THANK YOU, Fresh Codemonger!